# HTML5 video seek to end causes freeze

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, video

I have a HTML5 video element on my webpage and I want to create a custom timeline control for the video. However, I am having problems when I seek right to the end of the video. When I try to seek backwards, the video does not change (the ticker still moves though). Calling the "play" method does nothing either. The only thing that does seem to work is the "currentTime" and "ended" properties, which are still updated correctly.

Here is the HTML layout of my video and ticker (the "blocks" table has a z-index of 1000 and sits below the ticker, so it does not interfere with it):

```html
<div id="player">
<video width="500">
    <source src="Tutorial 1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<ul>
    <li id="play_pause" title=""><img src="control.png"></img></li>
    <li id="volume" title=""><img src="speaker_volume.png"></img></li>
    <li id="split" title=""><img src="scissors_plus.png"></img></li>
    <li id="merge" title=""><img src="film_minus.png"></img></li>
</ul>
<div id="timecode" class="modtime"><img src="mark_time.png"></img><div></div></div>
</div>
...
<div id="timeline">
<table id="blocks" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="CRZ">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 800px;"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="ticker"></div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS for the "ticker" and "timeline" elements:

```css
#timeline {
float: left;
width: 850px;
height: 30px;
background: lightblue;
margin-left: 25px;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 2px;
}

#ticker {
height: inherit;
width: 1px;
background: red;
z-index: 3000;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
cursor: col-resize;
opacity: 1;
}
```

I made the "ticker" element draggable using Jquery UI, creating an event handler to update the videos "currentTime" property during the drag. The "timecode" element displays the "currentTime" element in MM:SS.SS. This is still functional after seeking to the end.

```js
$("#ticker").draggable({ containment: "parent", axis: "x", cursor: "col-resize", grid: [ 1, 1 ], drag: function( event, ui ) { 
$("#stage2 video").prop("currentTime", ((ui.position.left - 1) * $("#stage2 video").prop("duration")) / ($("#timeline").width() - 2));
$("#timecode div").text(sec2smpte($("#stage2 video").prop("currentTime")));
}});
```

I also scripted the ticker to move when the video is playing (controlled by simply calling the "play" method when a button is clicked). The behaviour is apparent whether the video has been played or not:

```js
$("#stage2 video").on("timeupdate", function() {
$("#ticker").css("left", ($("#timeline").width() * $("#stage2 video").prop("currentTime")) / $("#stage2 video").prop("duration")  + "px");
$("#timecode div").text(sec2smpte($("#stage2 video").prop("currentTime")));
});

$("#play_pause").click(function() {

if ($("#play_pause img").attr("src") == "control.png")
{
    $("#play_pause img").attr("src", "control_pause.png");
    $("#stage2 video").trigger("play");
}
else
{
    $("#play_pause img").attr("src", "control.png");
    $("#stage2 video").trigger("pause");
}
});
```

**UPDATE:** I ran my source video through FFmpeg and that seemed to fix the issue. It seems to be a seeking problem with some .mp4 files. I also noticed that it would exhibit similar behaviour if it tried to seek backwards.

Comment: feel free to "answer your own question" as it were

Comment: @rogerdpack Ah this... I never did find a solution sadly, it was a downtime project I abandoned when the work picked up.

Comment: Yeah you could just post your own answer ("I used ffmpeg") and accept it :)

Comment: @rogerdpack It wouldn't have a been a solution in this case, though.